# Filtering data from other table based on column along with null values present in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables docs and geo

docs table:

```
id  category company headorg type
1   1        20      4       aaa
2   1        null    4       bbb
3   null     20      4       ccc
4   null     20      4       ddd
5   2        null    4       bbb
6   null     20      4       ccc
```

geo table:

```
id  category investor headorg 
1   1        20       4       
2   1        21       4      
3   1        22       4      
4   2        21       4      
5   2        22       4
```

Now I have to query docs table based on passing company=20 and also have to check the geo table too based on category.

Here docs.company is nothing but geo.investor

For eg take category 1, 
In filtering table geo for category 1 we investor 20 is present
so we should get doc records 1,2 even though the company is null in docs table.
Also if category is null for company 20 i.e doc records 3,4,6

So my query should return me 1,2,3,4,6

I wrote this but I get all the records 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
SELECT  * FROM doc d where (company is null  or company = 20) 
and 20 in ( select geo.investor from geo join doc d on d.category = geo.category)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM doc d 
WHERE d.company = 20 OR 
      d.category = (SELECT g.category FROM geo g WHERE g.investor = 20);
```

Or, to phrase this as a `JOIN`:

```
select d.*
from doc d left join
     geo g
     on d.category = g.category and g.investor = 20
where d.company = 20 or g.category is not null;
```